# return true if all the the records of first table exists in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have two table:

```
declare @t1 table (id int)
declare @t2 table (id int)


insert into @t1
select 1 union select 3 union select 7

insert into @t2
select 1 union select 3 union select 7 union select 9 union select 4

select count(*) from @t1 t inner join @t2 t1 on t.id = t1.id
```

i get the result for above query as 3. i need true or false if all the records in t1 exists in t2.

this is a simplified example of the real table structure. the real tables may have millions of records, so please let me know some optimized way of doing it

Comment: And if all the records exists, but on one table are duplicated, it still should be true?

Comment: Why do you want to check if every single record in one table (containing millions of rows) is present in another table? Whichever way you do this, you will still have to compare millions of rows with millions of other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id 
                      FROM   @t1 
                      EXCEPT 
                      SELECT id 
                      FROM   @t2) THEN 0 
         ELSE 1 
       END
```

Comment: thanks Martin! it looks nice, +1 for it but will it work fine with large tables, isn't the `set` operators slow.

Comment: @Vikram - No slower than any other way of doing an anti semi join. Speed will depend on your indexes and how many rows it needs to compare. In the case that it finds a row in `t1` not in `t2` then the `EXISTS` will allow it to exit early but if there are no such rows then it will need to compare all of the `t1` rows to discover this.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t1 table (id int)
declare @t2 table (id int)

insert into @t1
select 1 union select 3 union select 7

insert into @t2
select 1 union select 3 union select 7 union select 9 union select 4

if exists(
   select id from @t2
   except
   select id from @t1
)    print 'false'
else print 'all the records in t1 exists in t2'
```

Comment: You've got the tables the wrong way round for the message. You will find rows in `t2` that don't exist in `t1`

Answer (score 1):

Using `exists` (probably, it would be more efficient):

```
select
    case
        when not exists (select 1
            from @t1 t1
            where not exists(select 1 from @t2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id))
            then cast(1 as bit)
        else cast(0 as bit)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN 
              (SELECT COUNT(*) from t1 where 
                  not id IN (select id from t2)) = 0 THEN 
                  convert(bit, 1) 
             ELSE convert(bit, 0) END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing count of matched rows to the total rows in `@t1` may be more efficient. Sometimes you just need to try multiple methods and look at query plans to see which one works best in your situation. You'll need some test tables with a similar amount of data and proper indexes and such.

```
declare @t1 table (id int) 
declare @t2 table (id int) 

insert into @t1 
select 1 union select 3 union select 7

insert into @t2 
select 1 union select 3 union select 7 union select 9 union select 4 

select case 
  when (select count(*) from @t1 t join @t2 t1 on t.id = t1.id) = 
       (select count(*) from @t1) then 1 else 0
  end as rows_match
```